# Can a SPARQL query import or re-use a set of PREFIX definitions (namespace bindings)?

Tags: namespaces, sparql, prefix

I log my explorations of RDF data by executing SPARQL queries in a Jupyter notebook (Web-based REPL environment).

Very often I create a query by copying the previous query for tweaking.  The notebook fills up with SPARQL queries that all start with the same eight PREFIX definitions (e.g., `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>`).

I keep the PREFIX list short in order to reduce clutter, but this means I must often switch windows to search some other prefix that must be added (e.g., `PREFIX eurovoc: ...`).

Is there a way to save PREFIX definitions in a file, then simply import those definitions into a query?

Alternatively, since I currently execute the queries in Jupyter Notebook using the Apache JENA command-line utility [`arq`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/), I'd be happy for any command-line utility that allows a SPARQL query to be split into multiple files, or other such workarounds.

I searched for an answer to the question on `stackoverflow.com` and on the Web by trying many queries involving the words SPARQL, PREFIX, declaration, definition, reundant, import, re-use, reuse, namespace, binding, separate, file, and multiple, which I reproduce here in order to make this question more easily findable by others who may be asking the same question.

Comment: Not for arq - although it is just a matter of concatenating the prefixes with the query and feeding the output to the sparql command in whatever OS or environment you are in.

Comment: The following works:
`%%script bash

QUERY=$(cat prefixes.sparql query.sparql)

arq --data agro.n3 "$QUERY"
`
(where `%%script bash` says that everything which follows in the Jupyter notebook cell is interpreted by `bash`).  Not pretty, and it means I'd need to paste the queries into the notebook separately, but workable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon this question, while looking for something similar. AFAIK, SPARQL has no import directive, but there are tools like [rdf.sh](https://github.com/seebi/rdf.sh), which can look at all the prefixes you use in a file and build the required definitions (they're usually based on [prefix.cc](https://prefix.cc)).

Moreover, I've seen endpoints (eg, Fuseki) that have predefined prefix definitions and complete your SPARQL automatically, but relying on them makes queries less portable.